# return first index of element in list

Tags: python

I need to find out if the first character of each name in student_names is in list_char, but I can't figure out how to only use the first index of each name in the if line. I (think? I)need something like charAt from Java but name(0) won't work for me presumably since it's in the for loop?

```py
for name in student_names :
    if name(0) in list_char :
        raumA.append(name)
    else :
        raumB.append(name)
return(raumA, raumB)
```

Comment: it should be `if name[0] in list_char:` instead of `if name(0) in list_char :`

Comment: You can access it by calling `name[0]`. And take care of possibly empty student names - `if name and name[0] in list_char` will be a safer option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets for indexing.

```py
for name in student_names :
    if name[0] in list_char :
        raumA.append(name)
    else :
        raumB.append(name)
        return(raumA, raumB)
```